# Can i prevent my workflow 2013 with an Action to "Set Field in current Item" from creating new versions for the item

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow2013

I am working on a custom list inside my sharepoint 2016 farm. now i have added the following list workflow using SharePoint designer which mainly set/update 10 item's fields , as follow:-

[image]

now the workflow is configured to run when the item is created or updated. and when ever the workflow run 10 new versions will be created for the item.. so can anyone adivce if there is a way to update the item fields inside the WF without creating new versions? if this is not possible then can i at-least do all the updates inside one transaction so the result will be that the workflow will increment the item by one version instead of 10 ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the 'Update List Item' command - it will default to 'current item', and you can add your 10 columns to the list.

[image]

Comment: and what about the versioning? will it create one, 10 or none ?

Comment: can you adivce if using "Update List Item" instead of "Set  field in current item" will not cause a new version to be created ??

Comment: If you have versioning turned on for the list, yes, you will get a new version. You've changed data, so that's a new version. Update List Item will only create 1 version.

Comment: so the workflow manager 2013 does not provide a functionality which is similar to the SystemUpdate() i usually use inside my powershell which will update the item without creating new version or modifying the modified data and modified by ??

Comment: Nothing generic to SPD 2013 workflows. I don't know if you can dive into the http service call structure to do anything similar to a systemupdate() type of update, I've never investigated that.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure not t to turn on update workflow status.